# Javascript window.scroll doesn't work with options object in IE 11

Tags: javascript, scroll, internet-explorer-11

Using `window.scroll(x, y)` seems to work fine in IE 11 but it's not working using an options object e.g. `window.scroll({left: 0, top: 1000})`. Anyone have any ideas why this might be? I'm not seeing this question being asked anywhere else. Documentation here at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll). Is it just not supported in IE?

Comment: Why you need to specify left and top explicitly as in window.scroll(x, y), x is left and y is top only

Comment: @Pallavi aren't I specifying top and left explicitly in the second line example I gave?